# Can't I use "empty space" char as Target Path on Debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to load a DLL I'm making with Visual Studio 2015 using a 3rd party software for debug it. In this case, I'm creating a VST instrument and load it with SaviHost, following [this tutorial](http://www.martin-finke.de/blog/articles/audio-plugins-004-vst-and-au/#windows_debugging_setup).

This is my current setup:

[image]

the Target Path is `D:\Google Drive\Development\WDL-OL\IPlugExamples\DefaultProject\build-win\vst2\Win32\bin\DefaultProject.dll`.

How you can see, there is "empty space" in the path, and I think this make problem with VS, since when I try to F5 it, I see this message:

[image]

Google.dll makes no sense. It seems cut the path and "fail" loading a different resource? How can I fix this trouble?

I'd like to not move my whole workspace...

Comment: Did you try wrapping the path in quotes like you would do in the command line or a shortcut target?

Comment: @LoganCapaldo: you make my day! reply and you get +1!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use quotes to make sure that the path gets parsed as a single argument, as long as the program you're debugging uses the [typical rules on windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/17w5ykft(v=vs.85).aspx) for command line parsing.

E.g.

`"$(TargetPath)" /example`